# Problem with Ada plug in with VXWorks (workspace-4) in linux environment

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ada, vxworks, gnat

I am trying to install Ada in VxWorks (VM with Linux 16.04).
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7I-j8lhXs

But after selecting the AdaCore plug-in, an error message appears:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: GNATbench Integration with
>   SPARK 18.2.20180529 (com.adacore.gnatbench.spark.feature.group
>   18.2.20180529)   Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: GNATbench Platform 18.2.20180529 (com.adacore.gnatbench.feature.group
>   18.2.20180529) requires 'com.adacore.gnatbench.library.linux.x86_64 [18.2.20180529]' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: GNATbench Integration with SPARK 18.2.20180529 (com.adacore.gnatbench.spark.feature.group 18.2.20180529)
>       To: com.adacore.gnatbench.feature.group 2.5.0"

Where I can find the library that I am forgetting in the process?

Comment: Can you include a link to the tutorial you followed?  That may make it easier for us to replicate your problem.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7I-j8lhXs

Comment: I'm not sure it matters, but which Linux distribution you're using might also be helpful.  (Technically "Linux" is just the kernel, and it is not at version 16.04 yet.)

Comment: sorry you are right! I am using Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Comment: I’m surprised you managed to get hold of this software without having an AdaCore support contract. Their business model relies solely on the quality of the support they give, and it was very good when I was a supported customer.

Comment: Actually we have but the responsible of the profile in AdaCore is out and didn't leave us the code to enter in profile and open the ticket. So, to not waste time, I am trying to solve this way.

Comment: @Giovanni I think you should talk to your colleague, when he/she is back.  IIRC you can have an account on the AdaCore issue tracker for every supported developer, and not just for the one responsible for the contract with AdaCore.

Comment: @Jacob you are absolutely right I think the same and I have "flag-up" this bottleneck weeks ago. Thanks anyway I was hoping to solve fast  but obviously I have to wait.